# Splitting command line into arguments

Tags: javascript, regex

I have as string that I'm splitting into arguments using this regex:

```
/('[^']*'|"(\\"|[^"])*"|(?:\/(\\\/|[^\/])+\/[gimy]*)(:? |$)|(\\ |[^ ])+|[\w-]+)/gi;
```

it work fine for string like this:

```
'test "foo bar" baz /^asd [x]/ str\\ str 10 1e10';
```

exept regular expressions have space at the end because of `(:? |$)` I've fixed that by removing space after split, but is there a way to do this with just regex modification?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @alphabravo it should be `['foo bar', 'baz', '/^asd [x]/', 'str str', '10', '1e10']` but regex have space at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(:? |$)` to `(?=:? |$)` (`?=` is a positive lookahead, so it will enforce matching, but not be returned)

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to a lookahead (`(?=…)`):

```
/('[^']*'|"(\\"|[^"])*"|(?:\/(\\\/|[^\/])+\/[gimy]*)(?= |$)|(\\ |[^ ])+|[\w-]+)/gi;
```

I'd also consider changing the spaces to `\s` (and `[^ ]` to `\S`) in order to handle other whitespace characters like tabs and line breaks.